# Master Database Custom Table - Performance Issue?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

So, using this article (http://www.sswug.org/articles/viewarticle.aspx?id=22848)

```
Use master
Create table master.dbo.EvalRes (expVal real)
-go

Use databasename
GO
Create Function [dbo].[Eval] (@exp varchar(1000))
 returns real
as
begin

   declare @ans real
   declare @osqlStmt varchar(1000)

   set @osqlStmt = 'osql.exe -S Server\Instance -U evaler -P evaler -q ' + '" Insert into master.dbo.EvalRes (expVal) select ' + @exp + '"'
   exec master..xp_cmdShell @osqlStmt
   select @ans = expVal From master.dbo.EvalRes
   set @osqlStmt = 'osql.exe -S Server\Instance -U evaler -P evaler -q ' + '" delete master.dbo.EvalRes ' + '"'
   exec master..xp_cmdShell @osqlStmt
   return @ans
end

GO
Select  dbo.Eval('(7+4)*6-1-(3*4)+3')       
        as CalcPrice7
GO
```

I have created the table and an account specifically for accessing the evalres table. It works as desired. I substitute numerals for text in stored formulas that vary with each record:

```
BASE + Taxes + MARKUP
VALUE + Freight * .01
```

In our business model, we provide the server, so all this is set up before hand.

Questions:

If I have a proc that uses `dbo.Eval` 100 times or more, will this affect general server performance?

If I'm writing and deleting the one cell hundreds of times a day, how will this affect the master database performance?

Will I need a maintenance plan on the master to account for this?

Any other drawbacks?

Comment: Do you have a plan on how to deal with concurrency? If two clients use the function at the same time it looks like you will have two values in the table and you return one of them arbitrarily.

Comment: Is there a reason this can't be done using `sp_executesql`? I must be missing something here.

Comment: sp_executesql can't be used in a function, and then called by a proc to generate a calculated field. I've tried many ways around this. I can implement concurrency checks. And the values come from sanitized application created input anyway.

Comment: And you don't want to do this in your application because...?

Comment: Ah yes, okay. Will the expression to be evaluated only contain constants like in the example? If so, it wouldn't be that difficult to write a CLR function to parse and evaluate it. (Or better yet -- find an already-written-and-tested piece of code by searching.)

Comment: I was hoping to confine all the code to one layer. Yes, the application does this, but I have a new requirement for results in SQL as a pivot. I consider CLR as a separate layer (for maintenance reasons). BUT, I will check that out.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing a key point here, I don't understand why you would go to so much trouble to evaluate an expression.  Having said that, you certainly shouldn't do anything in `master`, and if you must, why not just do something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Eval 
(
    @Expression AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @cmd = 'SELECT ' + @Expression + ';';
    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;
END
GO
EXEC Eval '10 + 6';
```

***THIS IS HORRIBLE CODE AND I WOULDN'T RECOMMEND IT TO ANYONE***

This code represents an extreme security risk since `@Expression` could literally contain anything such as:

```
`1; DROP TABLE xyz;`
```

This would immediately drop the xyz table without warning.  This type of behavior is commonly referred to as a SQL Injection vulnerability.

Having said all that, running your procedure several hundred times a *day* is not a big issue.  I would hope you are already doing backups on `master` as a matter of due diligence.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say that this does not look like a good implementation of dbo.Eval.

Since this script uses xp_cmdshell and osql, it means that for every call the xp_cmdshell command shells out to the operating system, executes the OSQL command line utility (which has been replaced by the newer SQLCMD command line utility) and inserts the answer into the dbo.Eval table where you then select it out for your use.

That is a lot of overhead for a simple calculation.  Likewise, there is nothing in the stored procedure to prevent multiple uses of the EVAL function from running simultaneously.  Which would mean that you could easily get the wrong answer from a basic select due to the concurrency issue.

You might look into using dynamic SQL as Uday Kothari suggested using sp_executesql in his response to that post.  That certainly has less overhead.

Note: Mikael Eriksson also mentioned the concurrency issue. Other problems exist as well.